# How to find why a systemd service was stopped

Tags: systemd

I've got a systemd service that is not running (`systemctl status` says `Active: inactive (dead)` and `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`). The service's own logs suggest that it received a normal stop signal i.e. `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` (can't tell which) and exited cleanly. `systemctl is enabled` says `enabled`.

Because the service has `Type=simple` and `Restart=always`, I believe that systemd must deliberately have stopped the service (i.e. this isn't a bug in the binary where it thinks it got a phantom `SIGTERM`, and this also isn't something else directly `SIGTERM`ing the process behind systemd's back - in both of those cases systemd would have restarted the service after `RestartSec=120` seconds). Do I have that right so far?

Assuming I do, is there a way to find why systemd decided to stop the service?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421752/edit) to show complete `systemctl status` output. Note that a SIGTERM or SIGINT can come from many possible sources outside of systemd's control.

Comment: same question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1055005/how-to-ask-systemd-why-a-service-was-stopped